# Positioning 6 elements in two rows evenly - having trouble (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I've been trying a few different ways to position 6 different elements in this way:

[image: diagram]

I've tried using two separate unordered lists stacked on top of each other but I couldn't get them to scale with page stretch properly. I also tried using a table but I can't seem to get the elements to all position in the center of their individual tds.

Here is my css from my unordered lists:

```
.button ul {
    height: auto;
    list-style: none;
}

.button li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 18% 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

and these are contained within this:

```
.newfooterright {
    float: left;
    width: 33.333333%;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    height: 250px;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: RobotoLight;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

here's a jsfiddle with this method:
[jsFiddle for unordered list](http://jsfiddle.net/TfkdL/)

I think an unordered list is probably the way to go... I'm just not sure how to get all of the elements to align in the center of each li. The elements on the bottom seemed to be stuck in the bottom right corner of the li. The bottom elements are also widgets from google+, twitter, and facebook, so I'm not sure if that is affecting their position.

Basically the elements need to be able to do this:

- Scale with window width in terms of their spacing (to a point, I don't need an uber small phone layout or something. Something like padding-right or margin-right?)
- When the elements scale the bottom element needs to stay aligned with the top element in the center
- positioned like in the picture!

Any suggestions on how to get this positioned cleanly would be appreciated!

Thank you so much!

Comment: There is nothing in the fiddle. The result is blank

Comment: yeah it is because my images are only local, i can upload them quick

Comment: i was more looking for just a general good technique to do this rather than have someone code it for me ^^

Comment: So you are asking how to target every three elements?

Comment: What kind of content is in each `li`? A single line of text, image, any random html?

Comment: Sorry I had to pop out, each element contains an image! And not target 3 elements, just position them like in the image

Comment: A table is the most obvious approach and should be easy, so show us what you have tried in that department.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you might do it, I am proposing the following HTML scaffolding:

```
<div class="newfooterleft">
    <ul class="button">
        <li><a class="twitterbutton" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="facebookbutton" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="googleplusbutton" href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="widget">
        <li>(I put the corresponding widget here)</li>
        <li>(I put the corresponding widget here)</li>
        <li>(I put the corresponding widget here)</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and the following CSS:

```
.newfooterleft {
    width: 40%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: auto;
}

.twitterbutton {
    background: url("http://www.placekitten.com/100/100") no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
.twitterbutton:hover {
}

.facebookbutton {
    background: url("http://www.placekitten.com/100/100") no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
.facebookbutton:hover {
}

.googleplusbutton {
    background-image: url("http://www.placekitten.com/100/100");
    background-size: 100%;
}
.googleplusbutton:hover {
}

.newfooterleft ul {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.newfooterleft ul li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 33.3333%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-left: 1px solid red;
}
.newfooterleft ul li:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}
ul.button li {
    height: 100px;
}
.button li a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 62px;
    height: 62px;
}
.button {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
ul.widget li {
    background-color: white;
    height: 150px;
}
```

In this case, I am adjusting the unordered lists to behave like tables and table cells.

It works reasonably well except if the width gets too narrow, but this may be okay depending on your application.

You could use a min-width to constrain it.

You could also try some variations with `display: table-row`.

Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/2U3D9/

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you want to select every 3 elements, you have to use `:nth-child()`. In the parenthesis, you can put any combination of `n` and a digit. There are also some keywords, such as `odd` and `even`. So in this case, you are going to have 3 different `:nth-child()` selectors. It will look like this

```
li:nth-child(6n+1), li:nth-child(6n+2), li:nth-child(6n+3) {
  color:red;
}
```

The `6n` selects every sixth element, and the `+1` adds that number. So if you plug in `1`, you will get back `7` for the first selector, `8` for the second, and `9` for the third.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/bqZfc/) is a fiddle demonstrating this in use

[Here](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/) is an article explaining `nth-child` in more depth

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your li's should be all ready to collapse.
You could give your li's a fixed height and width (creating boxes if you will), then add a style for each image to have a relative position and use top and left to get them into position (remember, percentages can scale for you). I've dropped hints on how to accomplish this as you wanted to learn by doing, but let me know if you need the CSS!